# Compare comma separated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a requirement where in I should compare top row with previous rows of database records which  they are comma separated.
example :
My table data looks something like this:

```
      ID   Phase                Updated By
      1    Test1,Test2,Test3    sxmalla
      2    Test1,Test2          rkgauta
      3    Test1,Test3          sxmalla
```

I have to display somthing the most recent changes in Phase and who has updated.The comma seperated data is submitted with multiple chechboxes in front end. User can update them through multiple checkboxes in same page.
Here Test3 is most recent change,then below that Test2 is the most recent change and on third row the actual first entry.

I need to show the result as

```
      Phase        Updated By
      Test3        sxmalla
      Test2        rkgauta
      Test1,Test3  sxmalla
```

Here is the code that I currently using to compare 2 comma seperated rows

```
  ALTER Proc [dbo].[PMT_GetPhasesEditHistory]

  @Project_ID int
  As Begin
  SET NOCOUNT ON 
  Declare @added varchar(1000), @removed varchar(1000),@strN varchar(1000),@strO varchar(1000)
  DECLARE test_cursor CURSOR FOR                                    


  SET @strO=(SELECT TOP 1 P1.Phase from phase P1,Phase P2 where  P1.ID = P2.ID-1 and p1.project_id=@Project_ID order by p1.ID Desc)

  SET @strN =(SELECT TOP 1 P2.Phase from phase P1,Phase P2 
  where  P1.ID = P2.ID-1 and p1.project_id=@Project_ID order by p1.ID Desc)

  If object_id('dbo.#tN') is not null Begin ; drop table dbo.#tN ;End          

  CREATE TABLE dbo.#tN( var varchar(100));  insert into #tN select * from fnSplitStringAsTable(@strN,',')

  If object_id('dbo.#tO') is not null Begin; drop table dbo.#tO ;End          

  CREATE TABLE dbo.#tO (var varchar(100));  insert into #tO select * from fnSplitStringAsTable(@strO,',')

  Declare @i int
  Set @i=1
  Set @added = ''
  While @i != (select COUNT(*)+1 from #tN) 
  Begin
  if not exists(select VAR from #tO where var = (select Top 1 var from #tN where var in ( Select   Top (@i) VAR from #tN where Var in (Select Top (@i) var From #tN order by VAR desc) order by var asc)))
   Begin
   Set @added = @added + (select Top 1 var from #tN where var in ( Select Top (@i) VAR from #tN where Var in (Select Top (@i) var    From #tN order by VAR desc) order by var asc)) + ','
   End
   set @i=@i+1
  End

  If(len(@added) > 1) Begin; set @added = RTRIM(LEFT(@added,Len(@added) - 1)); End
  Select @added as Added

  drop table #tN;Drop table #tO
  End
```

Comment: please consider normalizing your data first. split your comma-separated data into real column and probably one more table

Comment: So, generally, you need to compare the last row (3) with the previous row (2) and to extract what "new" wast added in row (2). Then to compare row (2) with row (1) and check again what "new" was added in row (1)? Is this what you want?

Comment: so can you suggest how can I do that @MVP??

Comment: yes you got it @gotqn

Comment: the client is actually want to see most recent change on every entry and who has updated it @gonqn

Comment: @gotqn - mind giving us a practical example of storing a comma separated string in a RDBMS where it is "very practical"?

Comment: yes @gotqn I was stuck with somthing,and looking for some help over here.@paulsm4 if i am not correct,you can correct me,you cannot send me such comments...

Comment: @Raj What about the example above - for reducing the number of rows. Image situations with multiple columns and rows. Each row can have one more column with CSV (let's say 100, 200 or more values) or each row can be inserted the whole with a separated value. Using CSV will reduce the table size, the indexes size and with the right indexes in a given situation will lead to better scan performance. Again, I am not saying this is right way, I am saying that in one of our cases, working with our data we have found that this is the better solution.

Comment: Do some one have solution for this issue?@gotqn or @Raj ???

Comment: @gotqn: storing comma separated values might actually reduce the number of rows but I highly doubt it will improve the performance. But I'm glad to be *proven* wrong. So if you have a complete example that actually shows that using comma separated values increases the performance (**without** sacrificing data integrity) then please show it to us.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guess it can be easily proven. Try to do JOINS or WHERE, or even aggregate functions on a table with 15 million rows and then try to do the same operations on a table with  150 000 rows. In the first case, we have a lot of duplicated information (each row is repeated 100 times, in order to avoid the CSV) and in the second cased, we have a CSV with 100 values or only unique rows. Again, if you are going to do something with this CSV and you need to turn it into a table, you can gain nothing,but in our case the column is handled by the application and reduce the SQL time.

Comment: @gotqn: you didn't tell us how you implement foreign keys or check constraints in that CSV column. If CSV is so cool, then how about the performance of something like `select column1, sum(column2) from csv_table where column3 > 42 group by column1`. (where column1, column2, column3 are not "real" columns but obfuscated in your CSV string).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There is no need to argue that performing manipulations with the values in the CSV in the SQL is slow - you need too convert the CSV to rows first. In our case, the column is not connected with the SQL logic, it is sometimes returned to the application which is handling it. So, if I am not using this column in my procedures or functions, why to work with 15 millions instead 150 000 rows. I hope, you see my point. And again,there is no need to argue at all. I am sure you know that there are only few "absolute" truths in the SQL and the other things depend on the situation.

Comment: @gotqn You will not have 15 millions rows in that table, you will have another table with 15 million rows that you access only when you need. While there possibly might be a situation where CSV is useful, your example is not showing it.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic So, could you prove "your way" is faster or show when it is faster? I hope tonight to have some time to run some tests and make examples and come back to you guys.

Comment: guys instead of arguing,if i can get the results by normalizing the table or by storing each value seperately  how can I arrive to my result ?????

Comment: Spelling.  There is a rat in separate.

Comment: @gotqn If you are not using the csv in any sql logic then it is just a string.  This question is clearly about processing a csv.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
WITH CTE_Prep AS 
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) RN
    FROM phase
    CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(Phase,',')
)
,CTE_Result AS 
(
    SELECT ID, STUFF ((SELECT ', ' +Item 
                        FROM CTE_Prep c WHERE Item NOT IN (SELECT Item FROM CTE_Prep c2 WHERE c2.RN + 1 = c.RN)
                        AND c.Id = c3.ID
                        FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'') AS Phase
    FROM CTE_Prep c3
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT r.Phase, p.[Updated By] FROM CTE_Result r
LEFT JOIN phase p ON r.id = p.id
```

This is using `DelimitedSplit8K` function from [SQLServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) for splitting, but I'm sure you can do with your existing.

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd8d6/1)**

Comment: I am using sql 2000 production.I think this will not work for sql 2000 :-(

Comment: No it won't. You should have mentioned that "little" thing in the beginning :)

Comment: Yes I should have ,can we have any other solutions for this @Nanad Zivkovic

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try and answer the normalization question.

```
Table PhaseTest 
PhaseID   int
TestID    int  
PK  PhaseID,  TestID
(this PK will enforce no duplicate TestID in a PhaseID  

Table PhaseUser
PhaseID   int PK
UserID    int

Table Test
TestID    int PK
TestName  varchar

Table User 
UserID    int PK
UserName  varchar
```

this shows the results on separate lines (no comma)

```
select PT1.PhaseID, Test.TestName, User.UserName
  from PhaseTest PT1 
  left outer join PhaseTest PT2
    on PT2.PhaseID = PT1.PhaseID + 1 
   and PT2.TestID  = PT1.TestID
  join PhaseUser 
    on PhaseUser.UserID = PT1.UserID 
  join Test 
    on Test.TestID = PT1.UserID
 where PT2.PhaseID is null
 order by PT1.TestID
 union
select PT1.PhaseID, Test.TestName, User.UserName
  from PhaseTest PT1 
  join PhaseUser 
    on PhaseUser.UserID = PT1.UserID 
  join Test 
    on Test.TestID = PT1.UserID
 where PT1.PhaseID = (select max(PhaseID) from PhaseTest)
```